# Map.connect with a hyphen in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want `http://localhost:3000/note-1828` to map to a controller action. I've tried this:

```
  map.connect "note-:id",
    :controller => "annotations",
    :action => "show",
    :requirements => { :id => /\d+/ }
```

But it doesn't seem to work (`No route matches "/note-1828" with {:method=>:get}`). What should I do instead?

Answer (score 2):

Route variables (like `:id`) can only happen in between path separators, in this case, slashes.

Your best bet would be RESTing your routes, to use `/notes/:id` instead.

But, probably, you're rewriting an existing site and want to keep your URLs. In this case I'd use `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` to reroute like this:

```
RewriteRule note-(\d+) /notes/$1 [R=301]
```

(the `.htaccess` must obviously be in the `/public` directory)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Leonid. And in case you just want to make some "pretty" urls, you can apply the to_param method to your notes model. Thus:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-notes"
end
```

And adding a RESTful route:

```
map.resources :annotations, :as => "notes"
```

Would gave you something like:

```
http://yourdomain.com/annotations/1828-notes
```

If you don't want the "notes" part, you can map a route to something like

```
map.connect "/:id", :controller=>"annotations", :action=>"show"
```

and getting

```
http://yourdomain.com/1828-notes
```